# Multiple include tags on JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, jspinclude

I have some question about include tags.

Is it correct to use structure like?

```jsp
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${info == 'view_users'}">
        <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/view_users.jsp" />
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${info == 'view_products'}">
        <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/view_products.jsp" />
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${info == 'edit_product'}">
        <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/edit_product.jsp" />
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${info == 'view_categories'}">
        <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/view_categories.jsp" />
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Sometimes I have an exception `"JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP"`. Is my problem will be solved if I use `<%@ include` file tag? Or do I need to give up such a structure? All included pages have fixed structure, not dynamic.

Comment: Please post compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

The structure could be simplified but it won't resolve your compilation problems.

```
<c:import url="/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/${info}.jsp" />
```

Instead delegate this logic to controller (using MVC) to decide which view should be returned and properly initialize the view.

Comment: Why the unnecessary change to c:import?

Comment: @BalusC What's wrong with it? I prefer c:import over jsp:include.

Comment: Nothing. It's just an unnecessary change and confusing to starters without any explanation of the rationale behind the change.

Comment: @BalusC It doesn't matter which tag is used, because both works in this case. Actually OP was asked about static include, but I don't think it would resolve compilation errors.